# If value matches from list, insert corresponding value below

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to write some vba but not having much luck. I have column A with a whole list of values that I am counting and looping through. For Each value in column A, there can be a match in range C:D. If a value in column A matches a value in column C. I want to insert the corresponding value in column D below the Column A value. I am not too certain on what my IF then statement should look like. I have my counter and loop... I am just unsure where to go with the middle portion of the code.

```
Sub SetListOrder()
Dim wp As Worksheet
Dim ef As Long

Set wp = Workbooks("Packing Slip FIXED").Worksheets("Locate Order")

ef = wp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To ef

IF (UNSURE WHAT TO PLACE HERE!) THEN


Next i:

End Sub
```

Edit: adding sample data

[Sample Data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDip8.jpg)

In this example, I would like to insert a new row under the value in "A" where A=C. ie. Range in column "A" = Range in Column "C". I would like to then insert the value from "D". The new order in rows 4-6 would be:

4. Range
5. Order Group 1
6. 2604291

I already have written the code to manually move my sheets around to follow the specific order once I am able to get the names in said order.

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? It can be easily accomplished with a formula. (You could also enter the formula with VBA).

Comment: I would need VBA. I want to Insert a row below. The end goal will be to run code that will rearrange worksheets (ie physically move sheets with VBA). So I need a way to insert the correct sheet name below the named one. i.e If column A has a value "26202" in row 5 and Column C also has the value "26202". I need to insert a row between 5/6 and insert column D value. there for column A row 5 is "26202" and Column A row 6 is Column D value

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below code and use:

**Formula:**

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$D$5,2,0),"Missing")`

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowC As Long, i As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rngSearch = .Range("C1:D" & LastRowC)
        
        For i = 1 To LastRowA
        
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(.Range("A" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("D" & rngFound.Row).Value
            Else
                .Range("B" & i).Value = "Missing"
            End If
            
        Next i
        
    End With

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @BigBen that the simpler approach would be to insert a formula in column D that only replicates the column A value when a match is detected. Such a formula would probably look like the following -

```
=IF($A1=$C1,$A1,"")
```

This would be copied into cell D2 of your column and copied down as far as needed.

However, if you did want to achieve this with VBA and I have noted you used the word insert a value (as opposed to simple enter a value or copy & paste a value) then this could be your approach -

```
Sub SetListOrder()
  Dim wp As Worksheet
  Dim ef As Long
  Dim i As Long

    Set wp = Workbooks("Packing Slip FIXED").Worksheets("Locate Order")

    ef = wp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = ef To 1 Step -1
        If wp.Range("A" & i).Value = wp.Range("C" & i).Value Then
           wp.Range("D" & (i + 1)).Insert xlShiftDown
           wp.Range("D" & (i + 1)).Value = wp.Range("A" & i).Value
        
        Else
        End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

This approaches the problem in reverse by going up your column instead of going down. Note that by inserting your data, will cause each previous value to move down as well. If you don't want this, then simply erase the `.Insert` line and it will enter the value instead of inserting a cell.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I have tried implementing but this does not seem to do anything when ran on my end and I am unsure as to why. It debugs fine and steps all of the way through

Comment: Hi @pseif  I tested it with some made up sample data and worked as expected, but likely that I misinterpreted your requirements - I didn't realise you wanted to insert an entire row for example (I saw your comment to BigBen above) - so that's probably why not working for you. Can you amend your original question to show a screenshot of sample data (real or made up is fine) and explain what the final result should look like. Then will try to help again.

Comment: Hi there, I have updated the post. Let me know if I need to clarify a bit more!